# Loop Will Not End

Tags: vba, filter, pivot-table

I'm having trouble with ending a loop in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    With Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Description")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1

        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count

            If Not (.PivotItems(i).Value = "Option 1" Or _
                    .PivotItems(i).Value = "Option 2" Or _
                    .PivotItems(i).Value = "Option 3") Then

                .PivotItems(i).Visible = False

            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: What does your "trouble" look like?

Comment: I'm getting a Run-time error 1004: Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class.
It's hiding the proper pivot items, but it won't exit the loop

Comment: You must have at least one visible item ,so likely your code is trying to hide the last visible item.

Comment: But that's what the If statement is for - it prevents the code from hiding Option 1, 2, & 3. Which I've confirmed when exiting the code all of those options are still selected while the rest are deselected.

Comment: Maybe try adding `.ClearAllFilters` before entering the loop?

Comment: I tried ```.ClearAllFilters``` and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything else to add, except to suggest adding a `Debug.Print .PivotItems(i).Value` to your loop, to make sure the Values are what you expect them to be, and make sure your `If` is functioning as you expect.

Comment: Everything seems to be working, but it keeps adding a bunch of unnecessary False's. Is it going through all of the source data for these filters? Would there be a way to stop the loop after awhile?

Comment: Or maybe after i = 30?

Comment: I don't have any visibility to your data, so I can't offer much here - are you saying there are more pivot items than you expect?  And keeps adding false's where?